# Delete related Object in Hibernate and Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring

I have a `Person` that has a `List` of `Cars`, in my database I have 2 tables for this:

```
Person [id(PK), name, etc...]
Car [id(PK), personId(FK), colour, etc...]
```

So when I remove one Car from the List, and call `saveOrUpdateAll(carList)` in my PersonDao that uses HibernateTemplate in order to save my changes to the Person, I would get a car row in the table in wich personId is NULL, but I want that row to be deleted, not just "unlinked", is that possible? Should I change something in my hbm files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just had to set cascade="all,delete-orphan" in my hbm and worked!